# Drupal 6: listing in custom-node.tpl.php what fields are available to use for the current node?

Tags: php, database, drupal, drupal-6

I'm new to drupal.

Is there any way to list in my custom-node.tpl.php what fields are available to use for my current node?

For example, at View, when I write

```
print var_export($data,TRUE);
```

to php customfield, it gives me a list of available fields. is there any equality func. for using in any node.tpl.php?

Appreciate the help!

---

**[UPDATE]**

Devel Module lists all

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100630-ck73wr684wyi5mxbpypk8e4yp7.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100630-ck73wr684wyi5mxbpypk8e4yp7.jpg)

I can print field_gues_amenities as below;

```
print $node->field_quest_amenities[0]['view'];
```

but how can I print **taxonomy > name** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but how can I print taxonomy > name ?

Bellow will print the taxonomy name

```
print $node->taxonomy[1]->name
```

You can traverse objects using -> and traverse arrays using []

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php). However the easy way to do it in this case is to enable the devel and devel theamer modules and use the themer info box on the front end to inspect what is going on.

[update]

I belive you should loop through the taxonomy array and output the names. From memory it is taxonomy, then the taxonomy id rahter than a numerically ordered array.

Comment: woa Devel is the way! thanks a lot! I updated the question, can you please give a quick look! appreciate helps! thanks so much!